# Configure Istio with Fluentd throws timeout error

Tags: elasticsearch, istio, fluentd

https://istio.io/docs/tasks/telemetry/logs/fluentd/
When I try to run

```
kubectl apply -f samples/bookinfo/telemetry/fluentd-istio.yaml
```

I get:

> kubectl apply -f samples/bookinfo/telemetry/fluentd-istio.yaml Error
>   from server (Timeout): error when applying patch:
>   {"metadata":{"annotations":{"kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":""timestamp":"request.time"]]
>
> "apiVersion":"config.istio.io/v1alpha2" "kind":"instance"]} for:
>   "samples/bookinfo/telemetry/fluentd-istio.yaml": Timeout: request did
>   not complete within requested timeout 30s Error from server (Timeout):
>   error when creating "samples/bookinfo/telemetry/fluentd-istio.yaml":
>   Timeout: request did not complete within requested timeout 30s Error
>   from server (Timeout): error when creating
>   "samples/bookinfo/telemetry/fluentd-istio.yaml": Timeout: request did
>   not complete within requested timeout 30s

I have installed the fluentd daemon as previous step

```
kubectl apply -f logging-stack.yaml

namespace "logging" created
service "elasticsearch" created
deployment "elasticsearch" created
service "fluentd-es" created
deployment "fluentd-es" created
configmap "fluentd-es-config" created
service "kibana" created
deployment "kibana" created
```

Comment: Which `istioctl version` and `kubectl version` are you using?
And what are the outputs for `kubectl get handler -n istio-system`, `kubectl get instance -n istio-system` and `kubectl get rule -n istio-system`?

Comment: I got it working , actually my services fluentd had not spun up due to some issue with wrong image name and hence container did not start at all.